# Sharepoint API search for string with special characters

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, query, sharepoint-search

I try to search for a string like: `1001ˌtestcompanyˌtestcity` with the SharePoint Online search query:

```
var url = encodeURI("/_api/search/query?querytext='" + this.searchstring + "'&selectproperties='ListID,Path,FileType,SiteName,Title,isDocument,SitePath,SPSoteUrl,SPWebUrl,WebUrl'");
```

Note that I use `ˌ` which is not equal to the normal `,`.

I only want the search to return results that contain the exact string but I get any Document that Includes 1001, testcompany and testcity.

I already tried to put the string into `()`, `[]` or `{}` and also tried to put a `\` in front of every special character but I always ended with the result described above or with no results.

How do I have to modify my string to get the results I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling stemming in your query by adding `&enablestemming=false` (see [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#enablestemming)).

Per default, SharePoint search will split your search terms based on whitespace characters etc. and will also try to search for [word stems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem) of those terms. Disabling that functionality for your query might yield better results for you.

In additional, you should encode your search string by using `encodeURIComponent` to take account for characters that are invalid for a URL.

```
var url = "/_api/search/query" + 
    "?querytext='" + encodeURIComponent(this.searchstring) + "'" + 
    "&selectproperties='ListID,Path,FileType,SiteName,Title,isDocument,SitePath,SPSoteUrl,SPWebUrl,WebUrl'" + 
    "&enablestemming=false";
```

---

**Update:**

You could also try enclosing the search term with an additional double quotation mark, which is encoded as `%22` in URL components.

Encoding the search part of the URL like I proposed is typically the correct way to handle characters that are not allowed in URLs. Looking at your example of `1001ˌtestcompanyˌtestcity`, the `ˌ` (secondary stress) gets encoded to `%CB%8C`, i.e. into two characters. You could try the following example with the additional quotation mark, but in the worst case, the `ˌ` was "normalized away" by the indexing component when the item was crawled by SharePoint.

```
var url = "/_api/search/query" + 
    "?querytext='%22" + encodeURIComponent(this.searchstring) + "%22'" + 
    "&selectproperties='ListID,Path,FileType,SiteName,Title,isDocument,SitePath,SPSoteUrl,SPWebUrl,WebUrl'" + 
    "&enablestemming=false";
```

To analyze the value that is actually stored in the search index, you could retrieve that specific item with a `Path:<urlofitem>` query as search query and analyze the property value (using browser or something like the [Search Query Tool](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool)).

Comment: I tryed adding the "&enablestemming=false" but it didn't change the result. I also added the encodeURIComponent. After adding it I get zero results.

Comment: Added an update to my answer. You will most likely have to dig deeper by analyzing how the value of the item is stored in the search index @ElBiasto